# uninitialized constant Spree::ReturnAuthorizationReason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, spree

I am new to spree, and I am making a spree app. I was able to make a new spree app, and deploy onto heroku after some errors. Here is currently where I am;

1. Once everything was deployed on heroku, I visited domain_name.io/shop and got the heroku error page **something went wrong, if youre the owner check your logs**
2. I did that and saw this;

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "spree_preferences" does not
>   exist
>       remote:        LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"spree_preferences"'::reg...
>       remote:        ^
>       remote:        :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
>       remote:        pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.attt

which led to [this github issue](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/5864), which led to [this answer from another post](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/3749#issuecomment-69022963) on what to do.

3. I ran `heroku run rake db:bootstrap` and then got that error.
4. The exact error is;

> rake aborted!
>     StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> uninitialized constant Spree::ReturnAuthorizationReason/app/db/migrate/20150310072293_create_spree_return_authorization_reasons.spree.rb:14:in
>   `block (2 levels) in change'

5. When I searched for the file it was referring to in sublime 'find in folder', it came up that this file doesnt even exist in my repo.

I'm not quite sure what to do. At this point, would it be easier to delete this and start over? Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Spree are you running? The file won't exist locally unless you copied it over, but if you're on the latest version of Spree you can find the file here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/return_authorization_reason.rb

Comment: @NickM I'm running `gem 'spree', :github => 'spree/spree', :branch => '2-3-stable'` and I'm running that branch because spree fancy does not work for me on the latest stable branch. I checked for the file you linked and i do have that in my repo, but it looks like I dont have a migration file. At this point I think I'm just going to delete everything and start over.

Comment: did you actually create the migration files with the rake task?

Comment: Also, get db:migrate working locally before trying to do it on Heroku. All those migration problems should be the same as what you see in local dev